# Get json from another site

Tags: jquery, json

Its the first time i have to deal with json in jquery. And im facing some problems, when i open:

`http://localhost:3000/calendar/termine/24-11-2013`

In my browser i get:

```
[{"id":73539,"name":"Anneliese","input":"18-40"},{"id":73537,"name":"Appolonia","input":"14-20"}]
```

So when i simply copy it and at it as a variable my code works:

```
 var array = [{"id":73539,"name":"Anneliese","input":"18-40"},{"id":73537,"name":"Appolonia","input":"14-20"}]
```

Then i tried the same with jquery:

```
var array = $.getJSON("/calendar/termine/24-10-2013");
```

This somehow wont work! What did i wrong?

When i open the page `..termine/24-10-2013` the output looks like this so now im not 100 percent sure if its real json:

```
<html>

    <head> … </head>
    <body>
        <pre>

            [{"id":null,"name":"sara","input":"11"},…

        </pre>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: [**same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: What do you want to say with this?

Comment: John you said you want to get JSON from "another site", i.e., not from the same origin as the current page. Read the page adeneo linked to...

Comment: ^^ Not only that, but ports and protocols must match! Is your site on port 3000 ?

Comment: Yes on `http://localhost:3000/calendar/home/22-11-2013` i try to call it

Comment: So you're getting the JSON from your site then ?

Comment: Yes correct wont this work?

Comment: No, not really, as `array` will contain a promise and not the JSON, the answers below should work.

Comment: The solutions you provided me somehow wont work correctly, so now i updated my question! Because im not 100% sure if its real json

Comment: the header content-type should be Json type. This is a Html-file with rendered Json inside. The header continent-type have to be "application/json".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [`$.getJSON()` method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), it doesn't return the result, it returns a `jqXHR` object. You need to provide a callback to receive the results, and because the callback is called asynchronously you need to work with the result there:

```
$.getJSON("/calendar/termine/24-10-2013", function(array) {
     // do something with array here
});
```

> *"from another site"*

If you really are trying to retrieve data from a different domain then you will have a problem due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), but in your example the URL you are using seems to be a path on the same domain as the page. If it is a different domain you can use JSONP instead if the other domain supports it - of course if you control that page you can implement JSONP as an option yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the response, then set the variable.

```
var array;

$.getJSON("/calendar/termine/24-10-2013", function(data){
     array = data;
});
```

Comment: Note that your `json` variable won't actually hold json, it'll hold an array (because jQuery will have already parsed the json).

Comment: Sorry but it is not working when i call later `alert(array)` i get in the alet rwindow `undefined`

Comment: @JohnSmith - That's because the Ajax call is asynchronous - you are likely trying to use `array` before the callback function gets called. You need to work with the result directly in that callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the json data then parsing it then looping and fetching it using each like that:-

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery.get("your/url/that/get/json/",function(data) {
     data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {                   
    jQuery('#dataContainer').append(value.id+"<br>"+value.name);
    });
});
```

supposing you have any html area `<div id="dataContainer"></div>`

Hope this helpful.`